# R how to use 'and' function/ conditional operators

Tags: r, operators, conditional-statements

I have data as below. In "counting" column i want to return 1 if both conditions - (df$age[rowcount]>5 & df$age[rowcount]<8) are met. I am expecting to get value 1 in 'counting' column for row 2. what changes should i make to my code?on rest of the rows i want 'counting' value to be 0

```
df <- data.frame(sex=c('M','F','M'),occupation=c('Student','Analyst','Analyst'),age=c(5,6,9), marks=c(34,65,21))
df
for (rowcount in nrow(df))
{
  df$counting[rowcount]=df$age[rowcount]>5 & df$age[rowcount]<8
}
df
```

---------------------------update

as per the suggestions given below, i updated my code as below. I want to get 0,1,1 in 'counting' column. What changes should i make to my code?

```
df <- data.frame(sex=c('M','F','M'),occupation=c('Student','Analyst','Analyst'),age=c(5,6,9), marks=c(34,65,21))
df

df$counting <- sum(ifelse(df$age > 5 & df$age < 8, 1, 0),ifelse(df$marks > 20 & df$marks < 30, 1, 0))
df
```

Comment: @KaraWoo your answer works. Let me know how could i change if i want to put conditions on >1 columns (for example counting =1 if age>5 and age<8 and marks>20 and marks>50. I wouldnt prefer writing multiple ifelse statemetns

Comment: `ifelse(df$age > 5 & df$age < 8, ifelse(df$mark > 20 & df$mark < 50, 1, 0), 0)` you could try this.

Comment: Answer for the update: `df$counting <- ifelse((df$age > 5 & df$age < 8) | (df$marks >20 & df$marks <30), 1, 0)`

Comment: @ManojG that wont work for me as I am getting 1 if any one condition is true. I want to get 2 if both conditions are true

Comment: @ManojG ignore my question. I got the answer :)

Comment: Then instead `sum` use `+` like this, `df$counting <- ifelse(df$age < 8 & df$age >5, 1, 0) + ifelse(df$marks >20 & df$marks < 30, 1, 0)`

Comment: please post your answer below and i will select it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your loop that works. You can add additional conditions to the `if` statement if you need them.

```
for (rowcount in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  if (df$age[rowcount] > 5 & df$age[rowcount] < 8) {
    df$counting[rowcount] <- 1
  } else {
    df$counting[rowcount] <- 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifelse` as following,

```
df <- data.frame(sex=c('M','F','M'),occupation=c('Student','Analyst','Analyst'),age=c(5,6,9), marks=c(34,65,21))
df$counting <- ifelse(df$age > 5 & df$age < 8, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer for update: Instead `sum` use `+` like this,

```
df$counting <- ifelse(df$age < 8 & df$age >5, 1, 0) + ifelse(df$marks >20 & df$marks < 30, 1, 0)
```